# how to Control form objects according to user level defined by a SQL Table ?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am working on creating a POS application as vb.net windows form application. When it is completed more than 50 users will use the application with many privileges. So I thought of creating User Level based control system but I don't know how to go ahead since I'm so new to programming.

I have made following tables 2 tables in sql 2012 as,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserLevel] [int] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserLevel](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserLevel] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

adding new UserLevel and adding Users with UserLevels to the database from application form is ok with me.

Now I want to set form objects Enabled=true/false, Visible=true/false according to UserLevel of logged in user at logging page.

I would try something as follows at click event of Loggin button at logging form,  if there are only fixed userlevels and users but since many UserLevels and Users will be created in the future, I know following will not be success,

```
If userLevel=1 Then
   form1.button.enabled=False
   form2.textbox1.Visible=False
Else
End If
```

Therefor I am looking for a way to define objects property through a sql table.

can you please someone help me on this.

thank you so much.

Comment: Before you go much further you need to start encrypting your passwords. Storing them in plain text is borderline criminal. They should be salted and hashed. As for the question at hand....what is the question?

Comment: What is the best and simple way to control forms objects property according to userlevel of logged user?

Comment: If you have certain controls only visible to certain user levels I would put them all inside of a control (like a groupbox) and then you only need to deal with making the groupbox visible. No extra code changes that way if you add new admin type controls. You just put them on the panel and the rest takes care of itself.

Comment: Why is userlevel in a different table?  Seems like it is just another attribute for user. Before you go much further you need to work out what exactly what this entails.  In some cases all it boils down to is that user A cannot view, change or delete records by user B; in cases where it does involve form controls  design them around that so things can be enabled by container. and always hash passwords

Comment: User levels in a different table is because users such as admin can make more userlevels. Its like user group. So. All the users in that userlevel group will have same privileges. Ok always Hash password. Tnx.

Comment: @SeanLange. I got your idea. But then how to handle multiple groupboxes behaviors at runtime according to userlevel ?